# In what context does "ConsoleInput" miss?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace suma_cifrelor_unui_nr
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n;
            int suma = 0;

            Console.Write("Introdu numarul ");
            Console.Write("\n");
            n = int.Parse(ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true));
            while (n > 0)
            {
                suma = suma + n % 10;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            Console.Write("Suma cifrelor este ==");
            Console.Write(suma);

        }
    }
}
```

When I m trying to run this code the following error  pops up :

"The name 'ConsoleInput' does not exist in the current context"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSsCT.png)

Comment: Where did you copy that code from? My guess is you copied it from somewhere where that class and method is defined and you need to copy over that class and method over into this program.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `ReadToWhiteSpace` method on any framework classes related to the `Console`, and there isn't one called `ConsoleInput`. So at the moment, the answer to your question is "everywhere" until we get a clue where you found it.

Comment: I wrote it in visual studio and pasted it in here.

Comment: Yes,  but the question is, why do you think there's a `ConsoleInput` class *at all*? You must have got that idea from somewhere.

Comment: So I should rewrite with what the command in order to read the number n from the keyboard?

Comment: Are you trying to do a Codility test by any chance?

Comment: Well that is a completely different question. But let's start with _why did you even expect that code to work?_

Comment: figured it out .. no need to be so harsh btw

Comment: We aren't being harsh - we are trying to help. Part of that effort is to understand the context of your question - i.e. why you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

As expected `ConsoleInput` is a helper class so I did some google search,
And that's land me to [convert code from c++ to c#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f354e47-4cd5-4451-82cd-b5985cc9f809/convert-code-from-c-to-c?forum=csharpgeneral) and i found that words "with the 'ConsoleInput' helper class added by our converter", so try to check google before ask next time.

```cs
internal static class ConsoleInput
{
    private static bool goodLastRead = false;
    internal static bool LastReadWasGood
    {
        get
        {
            return goodLastRead;
        }
    }

    internal static string ReadToWhiteSpace(bool skipLeadingWhiteSpace)
    {
        string input = "";

        char nextChar;
        while (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            //accumulate leading white space if skipLeadingWhiteSpace is false:
            if (!skipLeadingWhiteSpace)
                input += nextChar;
        }
        //the first non white space character:
        input += nextChar;

        //accumulate characters until white space is reached:
        while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            input += nextChar;
        }

        goodLastRead = input.Length > 0;
        return input;
    }

    internal static string ScanfRead(string unwantedSequence = null, int maxFieldLength = -1)
    {
        string input = "";

        char nextChar;
        if (unwantedSequence != null)
        {
            nextChar = '\0';
            for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < unwantedSequence.Length; charIndex++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(unwantedSequence[charIndex]))
                {
                    //ignore all subsequent white space:
                    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
                    {
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //ensure each character matches the expected character in the sequence:
                    nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read();
                    if (nextChar != unwantedSequence[charIndex])
                        return null;
                }
            }

            input = nextChar.ToString();
            if (maxFieldLength == 1)
                return input;
        }

        while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            input += nextChar;
            if (maxFieldLength == input.Length)
                return input;
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
using System;

namespace suma_cifrelor_unui_nr
{
    internal static class ConsoleInput
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n;
            int suma = 0;

            Console.Write("Introdu numarul ");
            Console.Write("\n");
            n = int.Parse(ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true));
            while (n > 0)
            {
                suma = suma + n % 10;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            Console.Write("Suma cifrelor este ==");
            Console.Write(suma);

        }

        private static ReadOnlySpan<char> ReadToWhiteSpace(bool v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, that isn't an answer.

Comment: can you explain what your answer are doing .?